# What is the difference between const double and double const?

Tags: c++

I came across in a popular C++ blog the following code:

```
double const x = 1.0;
```

I know that `const double*` and `double* const` differ in a way that in the former the value is const while in the other the pointer is const. But what is the difference between `double const` and `const double`?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: It's explained as part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`double const x = 1.0`
is identical to
`const double x = 1.0`

Both are declaring a constant double-precision floating point variable.